# Why do I need to run Walk with a new subroutine?

Tags: go

I’m writing the [Walk function in the go tutorial](http://tour.golang.org/#72) that basically traverses a tree in-order. What I have works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree"
)

// Walk walks the tree t sending all values
// from the tree to the channel ch.
func Walk__helper(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    if (t == nil) {
        return
    }

    Walk__helper(t.Left, ch)
    ch <- t.Value
    Walk__helper(t.Right, ch)
}

func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    Walk__helper(t, ch)
    close(ch)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go Walk(tree.New(1), ch)
    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Println(v)   
    }
}
```

Why must I use `go Walk(tree.New(1), ch)` instead of just `Walk(tree.New(1), ch)`?

I was under the impression that the `go` keyword basically spawns a new thread. In that case, we’d run into issues since the for loop might run before the subroutine completes.

Strangely, when I take out the `go` keyword, I get a deadlock. This is rather counterintuitive to me. What exactly is the `go` keyword doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point here is `range` when coupled with a channel.

When you `range` over a channel (in this case, `ch`), it will wait for items to be sent on the channel before iterating through the loop. This is a safe, "blocking" action, that will not deadlock while it waits for the channel to receive an item.

The deadlock occurs when not using a goroutine because your channel isn't buffered. If you don't use a goroutine, then the method call is synchronous, `Walk` puts something on the channel.. and it blocks until that is popped off. It never gets popped off.. because the method call was synchronous.

> I was under the impression that the go keyword basically spawns a new thread

..that is incorrect. There are many more important implementation details required to understand what goes on there. You should separate your thought process of a goroutine from a thread.. and just think of a goroutine as a concurrently executing piece of code, without a "thread".

Comment: Oh hmm, thanks. Regarding how threads differ from goroutines, I suppose you mean that synchronization (mutexes, semaphores) can basically be implemented with channel buffers?

Comment: They are quite different. Goroutines are a an abstraction that sits above a Thread. The Go runtime time slices goroutines just like an operating system does Threads.. but it is much cheaper to do so. It can time slice multiple goroutines across a single thread. If a goroutine can be pre-empted to be blocking a thread.. the runtime will spawn a new thread and time slice the goroutines across to that one while the other thread is blocked. That's the _basic_ rundown of it.. there's more too it though.

Comment: At a low level, some key differences from OS threads: goroutines start w/a small stack that can later expand, so launching one doesn't take much time or RAM; Go's `net` package, channels, etc., make goroutines yield to Go's user-mode scheduler when certain blocking ops happen; and, when yielded to, the user-mode scheduler can pass control to another goroutine without a costly trip through kernel space. In some respects they're like what the Windows world calls "fibers."

Comment: @twotwotwo I was unaware of the term "fibers". I didn't realise there was an official term for the transition from user-mode to kernel-mode. Thanks for the info! :)